# Python giving a key error while inside a Try/Except loop

Tags: python

I am running the code:

**CODE**

```
def create_hec_kw(self, kw):
    print(f'Creating Keyword {kw}')
    data = {'name': kw, 'slug': kw.lower().replace(' ', '-')}
    response = requests.post(self.create_url('tags'), headers=self.get_headers(), json=data)
    # created_kw_id = response.json()['data']['term_id'] if response.json()['code'] else response.json()['id']
    print(f'The keyword response is {response.json()}')
    try:
      if response.json()['code']:
        created_kw_id = response.json()['data']['term_id']
      else: 
        created_kw_id = response.json()['id']
        print(f'The id is {created_kw_id}')
      return created_kw_id
    except TypeError:
      created_kw_id = ''
      return created_kw_id
```

I am getting an error `key not found "code"` when the response doesn't contain `code`. I understand why the error is occurring (the JSON response) doesn't contain that key.  What I want to understand is why is it crashing my app (Flask hosted on Heroku) instead of gracefully going to the `except TypeError` part of my code.

Isn't this the reason I would have a try loop?  I am sure I have done some thing wrong, but I wanted to better understand the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `KeyError` instead of `TypeError` to catch it.